# Python asyncio: interruptable task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a barebones skeleton fighting game with python asyncio.

```
class Skeleton(Creature):
    pass

class SkeletonAI():
    def __init__(self, skeleton,loop = None):
        self.loop = loop or asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.skeleton = skeleton
        self.action_task = None


    async def run(self):
        while True:
            #print(self.action_task, )
            if self.skeleton.alive and self.skeleton.target.alive:
                if self.skeleton.state == 'idle':
                    #ATTACK
                    self.skeleton.begin_attack()
                    self.action_task = self.loop.call_later(3, self.skeleton.action_complete)

            else:
                break


class Player(Creature):
    def attack_target(self, target):
        target.take_damage(self.damage)
        if target.state == 'attacking':
            target.state = 'idle'
            #interrupt attack

class Game():

    #Super simple game

    #The skeleton launches an attack, press anything to interrupt it 
    async def handle_sending(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
            max_workers=1,
        )
        while True:
            msg = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, input)
            print('got a message')
            if self.skeleton_ai.action_task:
                print('cancelling attack')
                self.skeleton_ai.action_task.cancel()
                self.skeleton_ai.skeleton.machine.set_state('idle')

                print('cancelled attack')
                self.skeleton_ai.action_task = None

    async def game_loop(self):
        player_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.handle_sending())
        skeleton_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.skeleton_ai.run())
    def __init__(self):
        self.task = None
        self.loop  = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.player = Player(name='ply')
        self.skeleton_ai = SkeletonAI(skeleton=Skeleton(name='bobby'))
        self.skeleton_ai.skeleton.target = self.player
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.game_loop())
        try:
            self.loop.run_forever()
        finally:
            pass
        loop.close()

Game()
```

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Player input and game output are async, so `input()` doesn't block. This works.
2. The skeleton prepares an attack, if it's not interrupted in 3 seconds, the attack deals damage to the player.
3. The player can input any text to interrupt the skeleton attack.

How can I make the skeleton's attack? I want a task I can interrupt at will and call a callback later. Currently everything just gets stuck. The `call_later` never calls.

Comment: I don't see how this is particularly a good use case for asyncio.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern for a async function with timeout and callback function. The clue is to catch the asyncio.TimeoutError and do your timeout logic. The function that is cancelled will not continue after it's current await position.

```
import asyncio

async def slow_function(seconds):
    print('starting slow computations')
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
    print('slow computations done')

async def timeout_callback():
    print('timeout called')

async def timeout_with_cb(fut, timeout, timeout_fut):
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await timeout_fut

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(
                        timeout_with_cb(slow_function(2), 1,
                        timeout_callback())))
```

This will print:

```
starting slow computations
timeout called
```

I guess this can help you to adapt your example (the provided example does not compile).